# Calculate degrees from group variables in panel data in R

Tags: r, networking

I have a longitudinal data-set that looks like this:

```
id  date    group
 1  jan-13  1
 2  jan-13  1
 3  jan-13  2
 1  fev-13  3
 2  fev-13  4
 2  fev-13  3
 3  fev-13  4
 1  mar-13  5
 2  mar-13  6
 3  mar-13  5
```

It represents a network, each individual is connected to other individuals in period t if they were in the same group in any period before t (including t). Therefore in feb-13 indidual 1 is only conected to individual 2.

I want to calculate the degrees for every individual at every period. In this case the final dataset that I want to create would look like this:

```
id  date    degree 
1   jan-13  1  
2   jan-13  1
3   jan-13  0
1   fev-13  1
2   fev-13  2
3   fev-13  1
1   mar-13  2
2   mar-13  2
3   mar-13  2
```

I have tried some things using for and aggregate but it is not very efficient (it is taking more than a day and hasn't finished). The data-set is very large, so usual packages that work with networks are not working here.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Ok, sorry, it seems I misunterstood your question. Did you check if any of the network data packages for R does what you want? If you create a relational data set it should be easy to get what you want, maybe this tutorial helps:

https://statnet.org/trac/raw-attachment/wiki/Resources/introToSNAinR_sunbelt_2012_tutorial.pdf

Comment: I need to calculate how many connections each individual has. I think that what your solution does is calculate the number of individuals per group. I cannot use this because this way I would count twice individuals that worked togheter in two different periods. I don't have the variable degree, that's the variable that I am interested in calculating.